# problem in installing packages in miniconda 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, miniconda, anaconda3

[discription of the problem can be seen in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlLWZ.png)I am using miniconda3 and it shows that no modules have been installed when I am accessing the module from Jupiter notebook.

I have installed the modules from miniconda prompt by `pip install pandas,sklearn` etc" the modules have been individually installed and it shows success full installation also, but when accessing it in jupyter notebook it shows error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install pip using `conda install pip`? You need to ensure that pip installs packages somewhere where miniconda looks for them. If you're installing common packages to be used inside conda, I'd recommend using the conda package manager to install them.

Comment: My guess is that the python interpreter running in Jupyter does not have access to the location of where pip installed the packages. In terminal, could you run ```conda list``` and check that your packages are there?